# Python: Assertion failured (Imshow)

Tags: python, opencv

I searched over the internet. I cant find solution on this matter. Someone please guide me how to fix it.I have a problem on following error. The command shows:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /home/sterlingm/builds/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 266
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_cv.py", line 7, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('img2',img2)
cv2.error: /home/sterlingm/builds/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:266: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

This code is about mean shift. It uses built in camera as the VideoCapture source.To capture a video, we need to create a VideoCapture object. Its argument can be the name of a video file.This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('13.mp4')

# take first frame of the video
ret,frame = cap.read()

# setup initial location of window
# r,h,c,w - region of image
#           simply hardcoded the values
r,h,c,w = 200,20,300,20  
track_window = (c,r,w,h)

# set up the ROI for tracking
roi = frame[r:r+h, c:c+w]
hsv_roi =  cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_roi, np.array((0., 60.,32.)), np.array((180.,255.,255.)))
roi_hist = cv2.calcHist([hsv_roi],[0],mask,[180],[0,180])
cv2.normalize(roi_hist,roi_hist,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

# Setup the termination criteria, either 10 iteration or move by at least 1 pt
term_crit = ( cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 1 )

while(1):
    ret ,frame = cap.read()

    if ret == True:
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        dst = cv2.calcBackProject([hsv],[0],roi_hist,[0,180],1)

        # apply meanshift to get the new location
        ret, track_window = cv2.meanShift(dst, track_window, term_crit)

        # Draw it on image
        x,y,w,h = track_window
        img2 = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), 255,2)
        cv2.imshow('img2',img2)

        k = cv2.waitKey(60) & 0xff
        if k == 27:
            break
        else:
            cv2.imwrite(chr(k)+".jpg",img2)

    else:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the right source file ? There's no `cv2.imshow('wfatwf',img)` line...

Comment: My mistake. Edited. same error

Comment: Still doesn't match the source you posted